# Data Encapsulation and Data Flow in PHP

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, object

I am rebuilding a website I run which provides tide tables. I am doing it with the Zend Framework and am attempting to make it as object oriented as possible. I have been thinking about the flow/process that will occur when a visitor requests a tide table from a location and how it returns.

I have come up with 2 different "types" of objects to use which will assist in this process. The first is basically a *helper* object that Zend Framework uses. The second is a *data* object (for lack of a better word) to encapsulate data that is passed between helpers. Here is a rough idea of the flow I am thinking about:

- **RequestHandler**

  - Receives array for request from site controller or from api controller.
  - Creates "data object" called **QueryData** and populates it with all information about the request.
  - Passes **QueryData** object to **LocationHandler**.
  - Returns the **ResponseData** object which was returned to it from the **LocationHandler**.
- **LocationHandler**

  - Receives **QueryData** object from **RequestHandler**
  - Does work finding location and creates a **LocationData** object to store it in.
  - Passes both **QueryData** and **LocationData** objects to different helpers such as **TideHandler** or **WeatherHandler** which return specific data for the initial query.
  - Returns an array of **ResponseData** objects which contains the responses returned to it from each of the specific helpers (TideHandler,WeatherHandler,etc)
- **TideHandler**

  - Receives **QueryData** and **LocationData** objects from **LocationHandler**.
  - Does work using data objects to find tide data. Creates a **ResponseData** object to store it in.
  - Returns **ResponseData** to **LocationHandler**.

In doing everything this way I get a "plug and play" OOP approach that allows me to add to this much easier (I think?). Sorry for the long explanation leading up to my question...

### **The Question:**

Is it common practice to encapsulate sets of data into an object (rather than an array) to be passed around to other objects which perform functions on it and send on new/modified objects? What are some other solutions or patterns that provide a similar level of functionality and flexibility?

Comment: In PHP?  If you care about encapsulation or type checking, sure.  Since PHP "arrays" are actually dictionaries, though, it doesn't matter much for passing PODS around.

Comment: Also, ZF feels a bit overengineered to me.  JMNSHO.  YMMV.

Comment: Would an object containing only properties use more resources than an associative array of equivalent design? Or is it pretty much equal...

Comment: The resource usage isn't really enough to worry about.  By the time you get to a point where it makes a difference, you're working with data sets too large for PHP to handle comfortably anyway.

Comment: Ok. So as far as separating concerns into different "handlers", is it bad practice to pass data through them and *waterfall* the return value back to the original request point?

Comment: A bit.  One benefit of the way ZF does it, is that along the way, you know you have -- for example -- a `QueryData`, and thus know what should and shouldn't be there.  At the very least, it's easier to test.  It seems like a bunch of gratuitous objects, but it could just be that they're suckily named.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are doing is perfectly fine practice, though keep in mind that your Data objects are just that - objects - so you may find that building some of the common methods into those objects or into their parent objects is quite handy. For myself, I'd say that if all you need is the data itself to pass around, then use an array. If you want to store the data in something that has the ability to manipulate or otherwise work on the data, use an object:

```
class MyData {
    protected $data = array();

    public function __construct($in_data)
    {
        $this->data = self::prepare_data($in_data);
    }

    protected static function prepare_data($data)
    {
        // do something to the data
    }
}

$myData = new MyData($_REQUEST['data']);
$myData->GetTideData(); // Etc.
```

"common practice" is really just style - if an approach (such as passing data objects around) works better for you, do it. If an array better suits your situation, go with that.

Comment: I think the main idea in my head with using objects is that later, if I need to, I can add methods to it. Additionally, it seems easier to **know** what to expect when I receive the object in another part of my code. An array almost has too much variation rather than standardization.

Comment: That depends on where you get your array, of course. If you're always processing the data then you have control over the structure. Objects do, however, allow you to build in those methods you want to have, as well as providing the ability to have a base class to extend from that provides basic functionality that all of your data objects will use.